# Is it possible possible to create a shared folder between users in AWS Sagemaker Studio?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-lab, amazon-sagemaker, jupyterhub

I'm currently trying to migrate a data science environment (jupyter notebook)running on Kubernetes to Sagemaker Studio.
I set up SSO and I now have privates work spaces for each user but I'd like to also have a shared folder between all the users. I've googled quite a bit to find an answer to this question without success.

Thanks for you help

Comment: it looks like the [default user directories are parts of an Elastic File System volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio-tasks-manage-storage.html). I'm not familiar with this setup but perhaps you could create an additional volume within EFS accessible by all the members of your team and mount that somewhere other than home?

Answer (score 1):

As of today, there isn't an option to have a shared folder between users in Studio. Each user profile gets a dedicated directory on EFS that's private to them.

If you're sharing data, S3 is an alternative option.

I work at AWS and my opinions are my own.